# How to add multiple numbers using nested loops?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am doing an assignment where I must use nested loops in order to add up the squares and cubes of integers from 1 to N (N being whatever the user inputs). For example, if the user input the number 5, the program is supposed to do "1²+2²+3²+4²+5²" and output the sum of those numbers, as well "1³+2³+3³+4³+5³" and output the sum of those numbers.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to code it in a way that I receive the proper output? This is what I wrote. Scanners were already added.

```
int limitNum = input.nextInt();
double squareNums:
double sumofSq = 0;
double cubedNums;
double sumofCubes = 0;


for(int s = 1; s <= limitNum; s++)
    {
        for(int c = 1; c <= limitNum; c++)
           {
     cubedNums = Math.pow(c, 3);
     sumofCubes = sumofCubes + cubedNums;
           }
       squareNums= Math.pow(s, 2);
       sumofSq = sumofSq + squareNums;
    }
```

But currently, when I run this program, the sum of the squares output correctly, but the sum of the cubes is always some big number. For example if 5 is used, sumofSq would output 55.0, but sumofCubes would output 1125.0.

Comment: Why would you use a nested loop? A single loop is sufficient.

Comment: @Mushroomator teacher wants us to. I'd be glad to use a single loop too.

Comment: Throw away that inner loop.  Do this with a single loop only.  If your teacher thinks this is a bad idea, you'll have to ask them for clarification, not us.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point using a nested loop as this would result in complexity of `O(n²)`. A single loop would be sufficient and be in complexity class `O(n)`.

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var squareSum = 0d;
        var cubeSum = 0d;
        var upperBound = 5;
        for(var i = 1; i <= upperBound; i++){
            squareSum += Math.pow(i, 2);
            cubeSum += Math.pow(i, 3);
        }
        System.out.printf("""
                Sum of first n squares: %s
                Sum of first n cubes: %s
                """, (int)squareSum, (int)cubeSum);
    }
}
```

In fact there is no need to loop at all => constant computation time no matter the size of the input `O(1)`. There is a well known formula which tells you the sum of the first `n` squares.

```
n(n+1)(2n+1)
------------ 
     6
```

> Please see [this](https://www.math-only-math.com/sum-of-the-squares-of-first-n-natural-numbers.html) for a proof.

The same holds true for the first `n` cubes.

```
n²(n+1)²
-------- 
   4
```

> Please see [this](https://www.math-only-math.com/sum-of-the-cubes-of-first-n-natural-numbers.html) for a proof.

The following program will therefore return the same result.

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var upperBound = 5;
        System.out.printf("""
                Sum of first n squares: %s
                Sum of first n cubes: %s
                """, sumOfFirstNSquares(upperBound), sumOfFirstNCubes(upperBound));
    }

    public static int sumOfFirstNSquares(int n){
        return (n * (n+1) * (2 * n + 1)) / 6;
    }

    public static int sumOfFirstNCubes(int n){
        return ((n * n) * (n+1) * (n+1)) / 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is no need to loop at all => constant computation time no matter the size of the input O(1). There is a well known formula which tells you the sum of the first n squares.

java

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).